# file path from \ to /

Tags: java, path

I have this problem: I am choosing a file from JFileChooser and if i take a system print i get this path: C:\Users\Joakim\Desktop\dude.txt and when i want to use this link to copy this file to another location i need to have the path like this:  C://Users/Joakim/Desktop/dude.txt
How can i do this?

```
public void upload(String username) throws RemoteException, NullPointerException{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(getProperty + "/desktop/");
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    } try {
        String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        System.out.println(fileName); //name of the file
        File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println(selectedFile); //path of the file
        //File path= selectedFile.replaceAll('/','/');
        String serverDirectory = ("C://Users/Joakim/Dropbox/Project RMI/SERVER/");
        byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile(selectedFile);
        BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverDirectory + fileName)); 
        output.write(filedata, 0, filedata.length);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("FileServer exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Edit: So this did not work out as i planed. I wanted to change the path to C://Users/Joakim/Desktop/dude.txt but thats not enough. I need to have //C://Users/Joakim/Desktop/dude.txt. The problem i have now is to get that and still use it as a File. I did test out

```
File newFil = new File("//" + selectedFile);
byte[] filedata = cf.downloadFile(nyFil);
```

This do not work for me. I still get out  C://Users/Joakim/Desktop/dude.txt
Do someone have a tip or two? :)

Comment: If you really have to, why not simply replacing `\` through `/` in the string?

Comment: The commented out line?  Uncomment it, and replace the first argument with `'\\'`.  And replace the first instance of `/` with two of 'em.

Comment: *"C:\Users\Joakim\Desktop\dude.txt and when i want to use this link to copy this file to another location i need to have the path like this: C://Users/Joakim/Desktop/dude.txt"* Why exactly do you need to convert it to an incorrect version of the path?  If you control the code that uses the information, you should fix that code.  If you do not control the code in which this is used, raise a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, try this :

```
String first = "C:\\Mine\\Java";
String second = first.replace("\\", "/");
second = second.replaceFirst("/", "//");
System.out.println(second);
```

OUTPUT :

[image: OUTPUT PATH]
Hope this might help in some way.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You should really be using the system properties [`file.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on
>   UNIX and "\" on Windows.

```
String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

You can also access the file separator as `File.separator`

Consider breaking up your path to incorporate the use of this property in lieu of forward or backward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: C:\Users  use double \

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
/**
 * Prepare dropbox path from the path.
 * 
 * @param path 
     *            that is to be formated.
 * @return 
     *        Return dropbox formated path.
 */
public static String createDropboxPathFormat(String path) {

    // Replaced all \ with / of the path.
    String dropboxPath = path.replaceAll("[\\\\]", "/");

    // Finally replaced all // with /
    dropboxPath = dropboxPath.replaceAll("[//]", "/");
    return dropboxPath;
}
```